# How to run huge processing in background?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have developed application for analysis data ie. domain name. When user provide 10 domains  the following javascript code working fine but when user start analysis for 100 domains, below code does not work. I used javascript to redirect to another page after 3 second of form submit because processing assign task takes at least 1 minute time.

```
function submitForm(){
        document.form1.button2.click();
    var t=setTimeout("redir()",3000);
    }
  function redir(){

       window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>menu/showmsg';

  }
```

When it is small task it is working fine but if there is big file to process javascript does not work, it wait till task completed from PHP side. 
Is there any option in AJAX or JQUERY or any finest code in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail? From what you've written I'm not sure what the problem is. Is the js taking to long? the php? do you have problems keeping it in sync? I really can't tell.

Comment: thanks. I have set ignore_user_abort(true); in PHP code. I want it process in background but when we submit form for processing it redirect to other page with message.

Comment: Though it seems you found a solution. I'd like to suggest building a job-queue instead. I guess this would help in the long run.

Comment: I have not got solution yet. above code is working only for small datas, my problem is with big datas. When I start processing with large data above javascript does not work.

Comment: Then think about my second comment. Don't wait for the job to be done, but instead implement an async mechanism where you add a job to a queue (which should be fast) and have an other system in place which you can *ask* if a specific job is ready. And the queue should work completely independent from that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use an iframe in the target page that runs the php. The page will load, and the iframe will wait for the php page. You can use some javascript to check for a change or flag in the iframe to move on with the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can sent all requests asynchronously using for example jQuery.ajax( url [, settings] ).

Here the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>menu/showmsg',
    error: function(){
        return true;
    },
    success: function(msg){ 
        // make what do you want
    }
});
```